# Tooltip & Typeahead not working with Angularytics

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using Tooltip & Typeahead from Angular-Twitter Bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Now when I implemented Angularytics (followed: http://www.blogeek.com.ar/2013/06/03/angularytics-the-solution-to-tracking-page-views-and-events-in-a-spa-with-angularjs/), both Tooltip & Typeahead are not working.

Is there anything else I need to do to make them work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the version conflicts of angular.js.

I resolved that conflict and it started working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any errors by looking into console in chrome dev tools.

Comment: You are right I changed all the min.js to regular one and got this error now. TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http://localhost/app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:2749:24

Comment: Do you know any idea why Angularytics is blocking the value coming from JSONP fro this Typeahead directive.

Comment: It's hard to say. I think the best way to resolve it is to isolate the problem and create JSFiddle. Often you find the solution during this process )